# Cannot insert data into many-to-many relations in asp.net using LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

I am developing a asp.net web api with angularjs project. My project is actually Hybrid Granularity Authentication. There are several tables in my project but there are only three tables that create problem with insertion. Three tables are AspNetRoles, RolePermission and Roles. And their relationship is:

[image]

There are three roles in Roles table. Employee, Manager and Admin. When admin changes any Role permission then the old Role permission is removed and a new permission is inserted into AspNetRoles table. However, an error occurs when this operation is executed. The error is:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.AspNetRoles'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.AspNetRoles'. The duplicate key value is (dbc1ae5c-a8a7-4aa9-b62e-0948e6e2856c)

My Code is to remove and update permission

```
public void SaveUpdateRolePermission(RoleWisePermission rolePermissionList)
    {
        var RoleObject = db.Roles.Where(s => s.Id == rolePermissionList.RoleId).FirstOrDefault();

        if (RoleObject.AspNetRoles.Any())
        {
            foreach (var rolePermission in RoleObject.AspNetRoles.ToList())
            {
                RoleObject.AspNetRoles.Remove(rolePermission);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        foreach (AspNetRoles Role in rolePermissionList.PermissionList.Distinct())
        {
            RoleObject.AspNetRoles.Add(Role);
        }


        db.SaveChanges();
        db.Dispose();

    } public class RoleWisePermission
{
    public List<AspNetRoles> PermissionList { get; set; }
    public System.Guid RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

A problem occurs when db.saveChanges(). Please help me solve this problem.

I already removed all the AspNetRoles related with RoleId. So there is no chance to duplicate ant items. And also remember that the problem is occurred even there is no data in Role Permission table.And i also check the distinct items of rolePermissionList.PermissionList. And if i remove data from Role object for specific Role id and then check that there are any AspNetRoles in Role Permission table that return true. How it possible where there are no data in Role Permission Table. Please help me to solve this problems

Answer (score 0):

At first glance this looks like it would likely be a case where your roleWisePermissions are not recognized as entities associated with the context. Whenever you are dealing with entities it's important to ensure that all references are set to entities that the context knows about. (Either loaded from that context, or attached to it.)  When a context is given an unknown entity the default behaviour is to attempt to insert it.

RoleObject was loaded from your current instance of the DbContext, however the roleWisePermissionList.AspNetRoles? From your example it isn't clear what the scope of "db" is, and where these entities/objects were populated. The class declaration for RoleWisePermission doesn't look like an entity declaration (No Key declaration, non-virtual collection) unless you are using an EntityTypeConfiguration for it.

With Many-to-Many relationships you generally want to load both applicable collections from the context, set up the replationships, and save. Often the approach I use is to select the entities in one go, then use those references in the association.

I.e.

```
var apsNetRoleIds = roleWisePermission.PermissionsList.Select(x=>x.PermisionId).ToList();
var aspNetRoles = db.AspNetRoles.Where(x=> aspNetRoleIds.Contains(x=> x.PermissionId);

RoleObject.AspNetRoles.AddRange(aspNetRoles); // Assuming List<>, otherwise, iterate and add.
```